# How only Admin can access to the page?

Tags: reactjs

How in my project only admin can access to `/page/admin`?

Here my code in module config:

```
 auth    : authRoles.admin,
routes  : [
    {
        path    : '/page/admin',
        component: React.lazy(() => import('./Page')),
    },
],
auth    : authRoles.notadmin,
routes  : [
    {
        path     : '/page',
        component: React.lazy(() => import('./Page'))
    }
  //
]
```

And this, is my auth role:

```
const authRoles = {
Admin : ['Admin'],
NotAdmin    : ['Admin', 'User'],};
```

The `page/admin`, is different from the `/page`

But the User "NotAdmin" can access too `page/admin`.

Comment: Is this syntax perhaps missing something? It looks like both your `auth` entries (and both your `routes`) are *in the same object*. Maybe there's a `{...}` around each pair (but inside the list) that wasn't included in the question?

Comment: BTW, don't worry about leaving out a greeting -- our format is more that of a FAQ or other set of Q&A pairs (writing for a future audience, not just current/immediate readers), so we try to keep more conversational content to the comments. See also [Should "hi", "thanks", taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on [meta].

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to understand your problem. You are using React Router, I assume. If yes, you have to create a `PrivateRoute`, then you should be able to check if someone is authenticated or has some role. Take a look on this page. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: @Milka did this answer help you? Is anything else you want to share with us?